# Hadoop order of operations

Tags: hadoop, partitioner, combiners

According to the attached image found on yahoo's hadoop tutorial, the order of operations is map > combine > partition which should be followed by reduce

Here is my an example key emmited by the map operation

```
LongValueSum:geo_US|1311722400|E        1
```

Assuming there are 100 keys of the same type, this should get combined as

```
geo_US|1311722400|E     100
```

Then i'd like to partition the keys by the value before the first pipe(|)
http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.2/streaming.html#A+Useful+Partitioner+Class+%28secondary+sort%2C+the+-partitioner+org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner+option%29

```
geo_US
```

so here's my streaming command

```
hadoop jar /usr/local/hadoop/contrib/streaming/hadoop-streaming-0.20.203.0.jar \
-D mapred.reduce.tasks=8 \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=1 \
-D mapred.text.key.partitioner.options=-k1,1 \
-D stream.map.output.field.separator=\| \
-file mapper.py \
-mapper mapper.py \
-file reducer.py \
-reducer reducer.py \
-combiner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.aggregate.ValueAggregatorReducer \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner \
-input input_file \
-output output_path
```

This is the error I get

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1311722400|E    1"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:419)
at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:468)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.aggregate.LongValueSum.addNextValue(LongValueSum.java:48)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.aggregate.ValueAggregatorReducer.reduce(ValueAggregatorReducer.java:59)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.aggregate.ValueAggregatorReducer.reduce(ValueAggregatorReducer.java:35)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$OldCombinerRunner.combine(Task.java:1349)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.sortAndSpill(MapTask.java:1435)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer.flush(MapTask.java:1297)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:371)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:259)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:253)
```

I looks like the **partitioner** is running **before** the **combiner**. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There is no guarantee that the Combiner will be run actually for hadoop versions > 0.16.
In hadoop 17, the combiner is not run if a single `<K,V>` occupies the entire sort buffer. in Versions > 0.18, the combiner can be run multiple times both in the map and reduce phases.

Basically yours algorithms should not be dependent on whether the Combine function is called, since its meant to be just an optimization. For more information check out the book [Haddop, A definitive guide](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521981).. found the snippet that talks about Combine functions on google books [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=bKPEwR-Pt6EC&pg=PA29&lpg=PA29&dq=Hadoop%20Combiner%20guarantee&source=bl&ots=kP7y4Ddezn&sig=43DkC1bKAeT2Op_W4GsH6VZUP9I&hl=en&ei=RgM-Tsf1DcLqrAfIoPnIBw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=Hadoop%20Combiner%20guarantee&f=false)

Comment: thnx for providing that information.I think there is a problem with the combiner running multiple times. I experienced it. My mapper is emitting keys like 
`LongValueSum:geo_US    1311722400    E        1`

**ValueAggregatorReducer.java** removes LongValueSum from the line and then combines the rows. Next time the combiner runs, it cannot find LongValueSum as the row prefix. Hence it throws StringIndexOutofBoundsException. I had to patch ValueAggregatorReducer.java to not do that. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You should never ideally modify your key in the Combiner. Essentially, Combiners should be used to only group Values. This article would give you a better understanding : http://developer.yahoo.com/hadoop/tutorial/module4.html#dataflow (It also tells you about the different phases indepth)

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the "Hadoop Definitive Guide" Chapter 6 Shuffle and Sort. Map output is bufferd in memory first. When the memory exceeds its threshold, map output will be written to disk. Before it writes to disk, data will be partitioned. Within each partition, data will be sorted by key. After that if there is combiner function, combine the sort output.

There may be many spill files on disk, if there at least 3 spill files, the combiner will be run again before the output is written to disk.

At last, all spill files will be merged into one file to reduce number of IO.

In short,
for mapper: map --> partition --> sort ---> combiner

and for reduer:  copy form mapper --> merge (combiner called if exists) ->  reduce